# org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'adminEmails' of bean class

Tags: java, spring

I got stuck on this error given below:

**Stack Trace**

```
Apr 16, 2014 12:21:23 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'collectionsWithProps' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'adminEmails' of bean class [com.student.spring.impl.CollectionsWithProps]: Bean property 'adminEmails' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at com.student.spring.test.MyTest.main(MyTest.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'adminEmails' of bean class [com.student.spring.impl.CollectionsWithProps]: Bean property 'adminEmails' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    ... 8 more
```

Here is my **MyTest.java**

```
package com.student.spring.test;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import com.student.spring.impl.CollectionsWithProps;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("beans.xml");
        BeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(resource);

        CollectionsWithProps cWP = (CollectionsWithProps) beanFactory
                .getBean("collectionsWithProps");
        System.out.println(cWP);
    }
}
```

Here is **CollectionsWithProps.java**

```
package com.student.spring.impl;

import java.util.Properties;

public class CollectionsWithProps {
    private Properties emails=null;
    public Properties getEmails() {
        return emails;
    }
    public void setEmails(Properties emails) {
        this.emails = emails;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "College [Props=" + emails + "]";
    }
}
```

Here is my **beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="collectionsWithProps" class="com.student.spring.impl.CollectionsWithProps">
        <property name="adminEmails">
            <props>
                <prop key="admin">admin@appa.com</prop>
                <prop key="support">support@appa.com"></prop>
                <prop key="hr">hr@appa.com</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for CollectionsWithProps?

Comment: I have now added the COllectionsWithProps.java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `beans.xml` you are trying to set the field `adminEmails` of `CollectionsWithProps`.
However the class doesn't have that field, it has the `emails` field.

Either fix `beans.xml` to use emails instead of `adminEmails`, or fix the source code of `CollectionsWithProps` be renaming `emails` to `adminEmails` (along with the getters and setters)

Comment: i have fixed beans.xml and changed "adminEmails" to "emails". It is working, but when i try to fix "emails" in COllectionsWithProps.java with "adminEmails" in setters as well as getters I am getting previous error again what am i doing wrong please tell me...

Comment: Have you named the field `adminEmails`, the getters `getAdminEmails` and the setters `setAdminEmails`?

Comment: Thanks I got the solution. But it want to ask a question why is it necessary to name the getter as getAdminEmails and setter as setAdminEmails?

Comment: I don't really now... Probably has to do with the fact that Spring adheres to the JavaBean spec. Could you accept either answer or the one from Himanshu Bhardwaj so future readers can now which the correct one is without having to read the comments? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is property name mismatch:

```
private Properties emails=null;
```

should ideally be:

```
private Properties adminEmails=null;
```

getters and setters should be renamed accordingly. This will match with what you have mentioned in the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it got  resolved by just removing getter. As I required only setter for my application. Sometimes Spring gives this error.

Answer (score -2):

Check for name value in .xml and Variables spelling And case should be same.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).